# Does Sint Maarten place exit stamps in passports with no entry stamp?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

When entering Saint-Martin (Grand-Case airport) an EU ID card is accepted, whereas to exit from Sint Maarten (Juliana Airport) a passport is required.

I wonder if you would get an exit stamp at Juliana Airport if having entered at Grand-Case and thus received no entry stamp (to clarify, there is no border between Saint-Martin and Sint Maarten)?

I tried calling Juliana Airport, but none of the phone numbers on their website are in operation.

Comment: @pnuts 1. If "by does it matter?" you mean "is it going to affect the travel plans?", the answer is no. 2. The logical purpose of exit stamps is to mark that you left within an acceptable period of time after entering (usually marked with an entry stamp). Without an entry stamp, however, the point of the exit stamp is lost - however I know at least some countries still give them. That's why I'm curious

Comment: you're in the islands - it's a total shambles. Anything at all could happen. Enjoy!

Comment: @pnuts Exit stamps without corresponding entries can raise eyebrows. This happened to me once in pre-Schengen Hungary (no stamp in at airport, but got stamped out leaving by train), and earned me a few extra questions next time I arrived. No major dramas though, and the OP would have an equally plausible explanation.

Comment: @jpatokal Yeah, something similar happened to me in Georgia. When entering by land from Turkey using an ID Card you get a slip with an entry stamp, while at other crossings (including Airports) you don't. Having entered from Azerbaijan by train, I had to explain myself when exiting for Turkey, but it wasn't too big of an issue (they gave me a slip with the exit stamp in the entry field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Saint-Martin (the French part of the island) is an overseas territory of the EU and you are allowed to stay there permanently, you would not be questioned when leaving from the Dutch part.

While in theory EU citizens don't enjoy an automatic right of residence in Dutch territories, this is impossible to enforce due to the lack of border control between the two parts of the island. Things might be different for non-EU citizens, but those are not allowed to enter either part of the island without getting a passport stamp, so the question is void.